# Is there a 'RadLabel' from Telerik?

Tags: telerik

I use the "Label" attribute in Telerik quite frequently. I like it because it helps me consistently structure tables. An example:

```
<ul class="box">
    <li><telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" Label="Name:"
           LabelCssClass="label" Enabled="false" Width="100%" /></li>
    <li><telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="MachineSize" Label="Password:"
           LabelCssClass="label" Width="100%" /></li>
</ul>
```

I've run into a problem. I would like to continue with the above layout/structure, but in some cases I have tables that simply dump output (ie no user input). To be consistent, I need a RadLabel, which takes an input of "Label" and "Text", and then aligns them appropriately in the overall table format. Is there such a thing?

---

I was just wondering... What about using the RadTextBox and just setting Enabled to 'false'? It kind of works, except that the text is now grayed out. How can I cleanly use the RadTextBox, just tweaking it to not show a border and not accept user input (and also not gray out the text)?

Comment: Since you're only dumping output in a table format, why not use the RadGrid?

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't, but you can create your own Label usercontrol that implements the System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label class, and has it's own properties.

You can create a 'Label' property in it that maps to the Text Property of System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label.